# WPF ResourceDictionary and Styling

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, resourcedictionary

Hello everybody at SO,

i have a problem in WPF. I have 2 (or more in the near future) ResourceDictionaries, one of them containing all Control Templates and another one which contains the icons and SolidColorBrushes. Since the first ResourceDictionary contains 2 styles for every Control, i want to make another Dictionary containing the colors and icons to use them in Dialogs, thus allowing to remove the redundant styles. I want to use always the base dictionary and the desired color dictionary, but here is the problem:

The templates can't access the colors in the other dictionary. I have tried the following methods:

Method 1: Referencing both dictionaries in the window

```
<ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="BaseUIStyle.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="UIStyles.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
```

Method 2: Referencing the color dictionary in the window and building the reference to the template dictionary in the color dictionary. Originally the setup was the same, but the other way round (window -> base -> color)

```
//Window XAML    
<ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="UIStyles.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>

//Color XAML
<ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="BaseUIStyle.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
```

The infamous .NET 4 Bug which many people encountered while styling their windows isn't IMO here, because the application has .NET 4.5 as target framework and even the second method won't go very deep (the bug happened if i understood this right when searching through 3 levels or deeper).

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

Move your resource dictionaries to the App.xaml, anything referenced in the App.xaml will be available to any file in the application.

Remember that resources are available to what they are added to and anything under that, so in your above example anything that is added to your window will have the resources available, the IDE may not autocomplete them, but if they are in the App.xaml it will.

I also don't see Color.xaml being referenced anywhere.

Depending on how top level you need the BaseUiStyle.xaml and UIStyles.xaml, you could end up with this in your App.xaml.

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Color.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="BaseUIStyle.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="UIStyles.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Comment: I can't find an App.xaml, possibly because of the way the project is constructed. The UIStyles.xaml contains the color.

Comment: Is this a WPF application? App.xaml is the default entry into the app and usually calls the MainWindow. It's fairly rare that you won't have an App.xaml; perhaps the file got renamed? Try searching for 'StartupUri' and see if you can find it that way.

Comment: What is your 'Startup object' set to in the properties for the application?